# Rails is returning html instead of json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I'm doing the Pro AngularJS book's tutorial.  Instead of using deployd I'm using rails on the backend.  I'm trying to load in products using JSON via `/api/v1/products` but when I printout the results the response is the layout html instead of json.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :store, only: :index
get '*app', to: 'store#index'

resources :products, only: :index
resources :sessions

namespace :api, constraints: {format: :json}, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :products
    resources :orders do
      resources :products
    end
  end
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_with @products
  end
end
```

**productListController.js**

```
var plCtrl = this;
plCtrl.data = {};

$http.get("/api/v1/products")
.success(function(data){
  plCtrl.data.products = data;
  console.log(plCtrl.data.products);
})
.error(function(error){
  plCtrl.data.error = error;
});
```

**development.log**

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:39 -0600
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (29.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`[0m
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
  Rendered store/index.html.slim within layouts/application (31.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.slim (2.3ms)
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`password_digest` = '$2a$10$FFHrMCASASl8cNMumUC8ZuNwTiZUmoe5i0i.jBW2./.h5iVlNxLZa' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.slim (70.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.slim (5.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 916ms (Views: 898.1ms | ActiveRecord: 17.7ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
  Rendered store/index.html.slim within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.slim (0.0ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`password_digest` = '$2a$10$FFHrMCASASl8cNMumUC8ZuNwTiZUmoe5i0i.jBW2./.h5iVlNxLZa' LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.slim (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.slim (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 120ms (Views: 119.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/assets/users-539b1b2d248fcacaf845c897cae976a6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/products-539b1b2d248fcacaf845c897cae976a6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/application-8dd662d13284733bbe54eda20bb23cc6.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/jquery-cebd6aebb61826123f8c2609ef491120.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs-e37afeff66df4b941f3d0e5103f67860.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/framework_and_overrides-59b1f67c44fcf715fcb2e3d8898788ac.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/stores-539b1b2d248fcacaf845c897cae976a6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/application-5c74ddfe9ec142533cae4e72117a6749.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/angular-6e1e5cba38bc1135b8f51b46fe8b1817.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/angular-resource-750afd404dad9b9a65500978142d97e6.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/angular-ui-router-a716fee384609b743dd55ab0468bf63f.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/store/controllers/productListControllers-347157b211789b303302e8bcc711500b.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router-a716fee384609b743dd55ab0468bf63f.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/store/app-5e5e1b9c4edcec361da040220caec84c.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/angular-resource/angular-resource-750afd404dad9b9a65500978142d97e6.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/angular/angular-6e1e5cba38bc1135b8f51b46fe8b1817.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/store/filters/customFilters-bfac291ac9405f569cf8cd59b6d64108.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/assets/store/templates/index-c54274a6b50c826831690b83850c84c1.html" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600


Started GET "/api/v1/products" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"app"=>"api/v1/products"}
  Rendered store/index.html.slim within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.slim (0.0ms)
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`password_digest` = '$2a$10$FFHrMCASASl8cNMumUC8ZuNwTiZUmoe5i0i.jBW2./.h5iVlNxLZa' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.slim (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 154ms (Views: 153.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: Can you write a unit test for the products controller to ensure that the data is json before being sent to the server?

Comment: To answer your question Rails logs are essential to share.

Comment: which logs do I need to share?

Comment: Rails app directory /log/development.log

Comment: I haven't been able to look into it as I've been swamped at work.  But don't worry, I will.  I think you're onto something, definitely.

Comment: @mikeglaz did you ever get this sorted? I had the same issue and it was happening because the URL that my service was using wasn't right. i.e. I started a rails server (on port 3000) and had my service use the url: '/1/posts/show_all.json' which meant it was in the wrong place. To fix it I had to give it the full url: 'http://localhost:3000/1/posts/show_all.json'

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do something like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @products }
end
```

instead of your `respond_with @products`

Comment: After reading your question again I guess your problem might be something else ^^)

Answer (score 1):

The logs show that HTML is requested:

> Started GET "/api/v1/products" for ::1 at 2015-11-08 10:16:43 -0600
>   Processing by StoreController#index as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"app"=>"api/v1/products"}

try to call for json instead:

```
$http.get("/api/v1/products.json")
```

Comment: I think the issue has to do with my routes.rb file because `/app/v1/products` is supposed to point to `Api::V1::ProductsController#index` rather it's calling `StoreController#index` with the `app` variable containing `/app/v1/products`